# TideSDK - Code Obfuscate

Tags: tidesdk

Is there some guide line for obfuscating my code, especially php in TideSDK, What are the possible options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google closure is available for JavaScript obfuscation by providing an option to the tidebuilder.py CLI utility while we work on a more permanent solution for all application Resources.